# Unable to understand why am I not sending mail to my host mail using PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

All I'm trying to do is just send an extremely basic e-mail to my host mail. The hosting service I'm currently using is https://www.ionos.com/ and I have a registered email with it. My website is already hosted and running. The code I'm trying to execute is this:

index.php

```
    <form class="" action="/contactform.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="">
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

contactform.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = 'info@installnewcooker.com';
    $headers = 'From '.$mail;
    $text = "You've received an e-mail from ".$name."\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $name, $text, $headers);
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

The e-mail I'm trying to send the message is info@installnewcooker.com as is seen in the code. Sadly I'm not receiving anything and I don't have any clue as to why. The PHP code is not giving any errors.

Comment: Most probably the `mail()` function is not allowed in your hosting. Or it requires configuration, like setting `sendmail_from` (try it, with `ini_set()`). I'd suggest you to use your SMTP or trying `sendmail`, it's fairly simple if you implement a library like PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite likely, you need a registered account *with authentication*. But the `mail()` function does not allow such authentication.

You probably want to install a suitable class such as PHPMailer. Simply supply the instance with your authentication information for your mail service, and you should be good.

If it *still* does not work, you can use the debug mode of PHPMailer to investigate. If you find yourself in such a situation, chances are that your Web provider **does not allow** emails to be sent by a PHP process, probably to avoid abuse and spamming. In that case, you need to talk to the provider and have the function enabled, so that the `mail()` function will work, and possibly will need to add a custom header to identify the email sender to your Web provider for accounting/monitoring purposes. As an alternative, they might supply you with a user/password pair suitable for use with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$mail;

mail($mailTo, $name, $text, $headers, "-f ".$mail);
```